# Do I need to use Marshal.ReleasComObject on 4.0 'dynamic' variables?

Tags: com, dynamic

I have the following C# code:

```
int CallFooMethod()
{
   Type type = TypeDelegator.GetTypeFromProgID("SomeCOMDll.SomeCOMClass");

   dynamic foo = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

   return (int)foo.Foo();
}
```

My question is, do I need to use Marshal.ReleaseComObject on the variable named foo?

I would normally do this if I was using the reflection in the usual way for invoking a method on a COM object, but since dynamic is all about late binding and magic, I wonder if variables of type dynamic will take care of this for me...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You shouldn't call it at all in most situtations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/01/marshal-releasecomobject-considered-dangerous.aspx), unless you really know what you're doing.

`dynamic` won't make a difference.  `dynamic` is just a different way to call methods on an object; it doesn't affect the object at all.

Comment: I read the above link and think it doesn't apply to my situation.

Comment: I am not using a COM Interop assembly or RCW , at least not one generated for by the compiler option for doing this(forget which one it is.)

In my case, I'm creating it and invoking methods via reflection, and I want explicit control of the lifetime of the object, 
ie: I want it to go away asap, not wait until garbage collection.

Comment: @Wes: `dynamic` won't make any difference.  It just controls method execution.

Comment: I'm accepting the answer, but noting that I don't agree w/ the link's central premise of, as one commenter put it ""X considered dangerous" for all values of X".  SLak's comment re: dynamic is the answer I'd like to accept